# Can this Pocahontas quote be traced back to a source?

Tags: reference, pocahontas

The quote is from the song "[Colors of the Wind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colors_of_the_Wind)" from Disney feature film *Pocahontas*:

> You think all the people who are people, are the people who look and think like you. But if you walk the footsteps of a stranger, you'll learn things you never knew you never knew.

Song writers are talented people but I believe they often get inspiration for text from somewhere else. Who might have inspired this?

Comment: Isn't that just a fancy way of saying "Walk a mile in someone else's shoes"?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any special knowledge of the authors, but my grandparents (one part Cherokee, the other part Osage) used to have a hanging in their house in the 70's that read, "Never judge a man until you've walked a mile in his moccasins."

[image]

There are many, many references online to this being an old Native American proverb. I'm skeptical<sup>*</sup>, but for our purposes here the story of it being a Native American saying *may* have been an influence. The lyrics in question seem to be saying roughly the same thing.

<sup>* - [This story](https://www.aaanativearts.com/walk-mile-in-his-moccasins), of it being written by Methodist minister Mary T. Lathrap in 1895 is one possible source.</sup>